# Consumer Protection act India 2019 and damaged good return replacement and refund

Tags: consumer-protection, india

Is there any clause in the consumer protection act 2019, which protects if the delivered product was delivered and defective, but the e-commerce company denied exchange or return?

Also, There was a 7-day refund policy.

I am not a lawyer I tried to read the consumer protection act 2019, and could not find such answers.

In such cases where an e-commerce company is denying return or exchange, can the customer claim refund legally?